# Make entire container clickable?

Tags: click

on the homepage of our site we display an ad container whose purpose is to call attention to a unique feature that only we offer.  Currently there is only one textlink on the container that reads LEARN MORE>>.  I feel it will be easier for users if the entire container is also clickable.  Do you see this as potentially hurting the clicks? I can only imagine that it will be well received because it is easier to click a big container.

[image]

Comment: Would the container and the link both go to the same place? Because that would be possible. But (from a technical perspective anyway) having the Learn More link go somewhere different then that's problematic as in HTML you can't contain a link within a link

Comment: Yes, they would both point to the same place

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the entire container should be clickable, not just the call to action text/button.  On my e-commerce site, all ADs, promotions, and even grid SKUs on product listing page are entirely clicable.  This, we've found, is easier for users to navigate because they won't have to pin point the exact link or button.

Unless you have multiple actionable elements in the container, making the entire container clicable is the way to go.

Some example from Apple and Amazon:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Even Scientifically it's much better if you have a bigger clickable area. 
But It's just about making the whole box clickable. You need to give right kind of feedback on HOVER of BOX, CALL TO ACTION.
Also, I would suggest you to strip off all the UNNECESSARY text from your ad. It would be much better if you could identify the KEY WORDS that give an idea about your service. As you are anyway explaining everything in details on a separate page.

Comment: Good points but my marketing team is adamant to show the "teaser text" on the container which kind of makes sense.  It's like a preview if you will

Comment: It only makes if your users are gonna read. From the snapshot, I gather that this ad is going to be placed among other elements on the screen. So, no matter how much text you put users won't bother to read a long paragraph, as they would be already distracted.

Answer (score 0):

I would just learn from how Google does. Google ads have **entire ad container clickable**, whether ad being shown on youtube video or a banner in a website ([check this random post I found which has google adsense](http://www.2createawebsite.com/money/google-adsense.html)).

Comment: Thanks @manoj! It's pretty clear what I need to do from all the answers I have received.  Thanks to all.